# Calculating uncertainties before aproximating exponential function

Tags: statistics

I have a [table of values](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-bjZSGwYfnF_wG6qVzDLlpzBzIAdtK3kLzqJ2xidVE4/edit#gid=0) that are supposed to be used as points for [exponential regression](http://fooplot.com/#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-) (least squares method).

[image: exponential function]

Values in both columns are uncertain, which means that the function itself is a little uncertain as well. The rule is:

$$real\ value = measured\ value \pm uncertainty$$

But how can I apply uncertainty to the points before approximation? How can I find the most extreme versions of the exponential functions to get the real value distribution?

Comment: Is this a kind of diode you're measuring the current and tension? I'm just asking out of curiosity :) 
Tell me if understood correctly, you want to have three curves on your graphic, the two others being the ones relatively to the addition and substraction of the uncertainty?

Comment: Yes, I want to combine the values so that I get the most deviant exponentials that are deemed possible. And you're right, here is the [complete task](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/141951/20590). It's giving me a hard time.

Comment: :D , I've been there too. My school is called "école supérieure d'électricité " = " superior school of electricity", I've suffered as well on this. How do you evaluate the uncertainty? 
Because for a start I'd substract it to each of your measures, ask for an exponential regression on the shifted values. Now it depends how the exponential regression is implemented. Is it automatic or do you have to plot th log of your values and get a straight line?

Comment: I'm plotting it using internet calculators. Here is a [plot](http://bit.ly/10qziFJ) where red comes from smallest possible values, red comes from largest.

Comment: Ok I've read your post of physics.stackexchange, I think you got what you wanted essentially. $ \alpha$ is your coefficient $\frac{e}{kT}$, so you can get your boltzmann constant (k). Do that for each of your curves (measured, -uncertainty, +uncertainty), you will get three values of k from which you will get the uncertainty on k. Is it what you were looking for?

Comment: That't the problem - is `-uncertainty` really the most extreme deviation from `measured` when the function is plotted? If you look on the graph, the red is almost the same as green - the deviation is quite asymmetric. If I had more time, I could probably let Matlab plot all the combinations of +-uncertainty to find the most deviated functions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18093/discussion-between-tomas-zato-and-mvggz).

Answer (score 1):

You want to evaluate the boltzmann constant when you study a PN transition diode, with uncertainty on both current and tension.

I'd rather use a linear regression with the ln of the relation existing between I and U :

ln(I/A) = b*U (alpha is too long to write) , with : b = $\frac{e}{kT}$

Question is: how to minimize or maximize the coefficient b? That's what'll give you your most deviated functions.
Then I think what is the most deviated way of injecting uncertainty is:

you want to maximize b => maximize I and minimize U : +A , -V

you want minimize b => minimize I and maximize U : -A , +V

What do you think?

Comment: Our teacher has instructed me to use special script located on school website. That script calculates the uncertainties of the coefficients based on the deviations of points from the curve. I don't think this is a realistic approach but I don't have a better idea.